# How to implement a For loop in Clojure

Tags: arrays, loops, clojure, for-loop

I'd like to implement this little code in Clojure, but I am struggling:

```cpp
struct mystruct {
   int id;
   int price;
};

mystruct mydata[10];

for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
  myfunction(mydata[i].id, mydata[i].price);
  //other things...
}
```

I am a beginner with Clojure and it's really complicated for me to do something simple like this, but I am really trying to learn as much as possible as I know that there are great advantages with Clojure such as using refs...

I would really appreciate it if somebody could help me. Thanks!!

Comment: Usually in the functional realm it's best to stick to map, apply, and reduce.  Map has an implied for-loop ^.^

Answer (score 44, accepted):

One way to translate an imperative for loop to Clojure is to use the `for` macro.

```
(for [i (range 10)] (inc i))
```

The above function will return all the numbers from 0 to 9 incremented by 1. However, it appears you simply want to iterate over a sequential collection and use each item. If that's all that you need, then you don't need to reference an index value, instead you can reference each item directly.

```
(for [d my-vec-of-data] (my-function d))
```

However, for this simple case, the `map` function would probably be a better choice because it is designed to invoke functions with arguments from collections. The following example is equivalent to the use of `for` above.

```
(map my-function my-vec-of-data)
```

Both `map` and `for` return a collection of values made up of the  values returned by `my-function`. This is because Clojure's data structures are immutable, so it's necessary to have a new collection returned. If that isn't what you need or if your function has side effects,  you could use `doseq` instead of `for`, which returns `nil`.

Comment: does 'i' increment automatically?

Comment: @nuvio: `i` will be the actual item in the sequence, not the index. And yes, the `for` macro will handle iterating the sequence for you.

Comment: "doseq" is great for functions where you don't need a return val because it returns a single nil instead of 1-per-element

Comment: @Chuck how can you get the actual count, since i is the actual item?

Answer (score 39):

Jeremy's answer is good for how to do a for loop in idiomatic Clojure.

If you really want an imperative-style for loop in Clojure, you can create one with this macro:

```
(defmacro for-loop [[sym init check change :as params] & steps]
 `(loop [~sym ~init value# nil]
    (if ~check
      (let [new-value# (do ~@steps)]
        (recur ~change new-value#))
      value#)))
```

Usage as follows:

```
(for-loop [i 0 (< i 10) (inc i)] 
  (println i))
```

Comment: I love how in Clojure if your missing a language feature, instead of waiting for it to be added to a future version, you can just write your own.

Answer (score 2):

`doseq` does something similar to a `for-loop`
USAGE:

```
(doseq [i (for [i (range 10)] (inc i))]
    (println "i=" i))
```

The binding is similar to that of `for` in Clojure. However, it does not return a list by evaluating an expression inside the `doseq`. It performs the expression for each value in the sequence and returns `nil`.

To loop through a seq, you can simply use:

```
(doseq [value list]
    (println "Your expression here" value)
```