# How to do a for-loop in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, quil

I'm learning myself some Clojure and I'm using Quil. I would like to know how to translate a for-loop into Clojure:

This is how I would do it in Java or similar languages:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < numSides; i++ ) {
    float posX = cos( theta * i );
    float posY = sin( theta * i );
    ellipse( posX, posY, polySize, polySize );
}
```

My Clojure attempt:

```
  (let [theta (/ PI num-sides)
        angle (range 0 num-sides)
        pos-x (cos (* theta angle))
        pos-y (sin (* theta angle))]
    (dorun (map #(ellipse % % % %) pos-x pos-y poly-size poly-size)))
```

Comment: found similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981943/how-to-implement-a-for-loop-in-clojure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All the ways that you have looked for are basically to work with sequences where as a loop is about executing things for a specific number of times. Clojure provide `dotimes` to do things for certain number of times:

```
(dotimes [i 10]
  (println i))
```

So your code becomes something like:

```
 (dotimes [i num-sides]
   (let [pos-x (cos (* theta i))
         pos-y (sin (* theta i))]
         (ellipse pos-x pos-y poly-size poly-size)))
```

Answer (score 4):

If you genuinely want an C-style `for` loop, then my [clojure-utils](https://github.com/mikera/clojure-utils) libray has a handy for-loop macro that lets you do stuff like:

```
(for-loop [i 0 , (< i num-sides) , (inc i)]
  ... do stuff.....)
```

Normally however, I will find myself using one of the following:

- `(dotimes [i num-sides] ....)` - do something a specific number of times
- `(doseq [x some-sequence] ....)` - do something for every element in a sequence
- `(for [i (range n)] ...)` - constructing a list with n elements

Comment: How about making the macro more C-ish, so that we can do:                    `(for-loop [ [i 1 j 1] (< i 10)  [i (inc i) j (* j i)] ] .....)`

Comment: @Ankur interesting idea.... haven't needed that myself but can see the value for some use cases.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is somewhat academic, but I like using Clojure's "for comprehensions" for this kind of thing.  The code would look like this:

```
(dorun
  (for [i (range num-sides)
        :let [pos-x (Math/cos (* i theta))
              pos-y (Math/sin (* i theta))]]
    (quil.core/ellipse pos-x pos-y poly-size poly-size)))
```

Comment: But `for` is constructing a lazy sequence, unnecessarily, in this case.  If you don't need the output sequences, as in this case, you can do the same thing--with the same binding tricks--using `doseq`.  Simply replace `for` by `doseq` in the above code. In many situations, the cost of producing the additional sequence is negligible, so that the only advantage of `doseq` is that it communicates to readers that you're not trying to create a sequence.  In some situations the cost of creating an unnecessary sequence can make a difference in performance, however.

Answer (score 1):

`Doseq` with `range` is often appropriate for looping over a specific number of values in order to create side effects. I would implement your loop as follows:

```
(doseq [i (range 0 num-sides)]
  (ellipse (cos (* theta i)) 
           (sin (* theta i)) 
           poly-size 
           poly-size))
```