# How to use macro inside a function?

Tags: macros, clojure

I created a for loop macro for clojure (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9981943/how-to-implement-a-for-loop-in-clojure/10056715#10056715)), which is as follows:

```
(defmacro for-loop [[sym init check change :as params] & steps]
 `(loop [~sym ~init value# nil]
    (if ~check
      (let [new-value# (do ~@steps)]
        (recur ~change new-value#))
      value#)))
```

Now, I want to use this for-loop inside some function, but I can't figure out how to use it inside a function. Could somebody guide me on this, or give me an example with a simple usage of this inside a function?

Comment: How did you write this macro if you have no idea how to use it? Using it inside a function is much the same as using it from anywhere else. Do you have any specific questions, or an approach you've tried that doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

If you turn it into a function by changing `defmacro` to `defn`, then, for example,

```
(for-loop '[i 0 (< i 10) (inc i)] '(* 2 i))
```

... produces (stripping the namespace qualifiers)

```
(loop [i 0 value__11639__auto__ nil]
  (if (< i 10)
    (let [new-value__11640__auto__ (do (* 2 i))]
      (recur (inc i) new-value__11640__auto__))
    value__11639__auto__))
```

Study this to see what it does.